# What does it mean to generate a category by a set of objects?

Tags: category-theory, definition, abelian-categories

Let me start by stating that I'm not looking for the definition of generator of a category.

Let $C$ be a an Abelian category. Let $S$ be a set of objects in $C$.

> What does it mean to consider the category generated by objects in $S$ and their direct sums?

Edit : I know there is a definition of generator of a category which is misleading and should be called a separator. I'm looking for something more along the lines of a group/ring generated by a set.  I'm probably looking for something like the smallest Abelian category generated by that set and closed under direct sums.

Comment: I meant to say that generator of a category is actually a misleading term as has been explained in other posts in this site. The correct term should be seperator. But I was wondering if there is a different notion of generation that behaves like how "generating a group/ring by a set" behaves.

Comment: I expect a definition that would somehow produce a Abelian category out of the given set of objects. Something like a smallest Abelian category containing S just like smallest group containing S would mean.

Comment: That is really helpful to understanding what you want explained.  Please edit the body of your Question to include that in fairly complete detail.

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: I mean, how about "The smallest Abelian category containing $S$?"

Comment: Are you familiar with [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff's_theorem), often referred to as the HSP theorem?

Comment: @hardmath no I am not. Can you tell me in short what it says?

Comment: There is a subject "universal algebra" introduced by Birkhoff, which characterizes those algebraic theories (called somewhat confusingly *varieties of algebras*) that are axiomatized by equational identities.  A good example is the theory of groups, and an example of something that is not a variety in this sense is the theory of fields.  Birkhoff showed a theory is a variety if and only if its models are closed under the operations of taking homomorphisms, subalgebras, and direct products. Note that a product of groups is a group, but a product of fields is not usually a field.